# Cumulative amount by report dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

I have two tables

sales

| id | colour | payment_date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | 2023-01-04 | 2 |
| 1 | green | 2023-01-04 | 5 |
| 2 | green | 2023-01-04 | 1 |
| 2 | green | 2023-02-04 | 1 |
| 2 | green | 2023-03-04 | 1 |
| 2 | green | 2023-04-04 | 1 |

report_dates

| date |
| --- |
| 2022-12-31 |
| 2023-01-31 |
| 2023-02-28 |
| 2023-03-31 |
| 2023-04-30 |
| 2023-05-31 |
| 2023-06-30 |

My aim is cumulative amount by report dates

I get cumulative amount by EOMONTH of payment_dates

```
SELECT
    sales.id  
    ,EOMONTH(sales.payment_date)  
    ,sales.colour
    ,SUM(sales.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY sales.id, sales.colour ORDER BY EOMONTH(sales.payment_date)) 
FROM sales
ORDER BY pl.AGREEMENT_RK, pl.OPER_DATE
```

How to join with report dates and get report like this?
EDITED: report dates before sales date doesn't needed

| id | colour | date | cum_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | 2023-01-31 | 2 |
| 1 | red | 2023-02-28 | 2 |
| 1 | red | 2023-03-31 | 2 |
| 1 | red | 2023-04-30 | 2 |
| 1 | red | 2023-05-31 | 2 |
| 1 | red | 2023-06-30 | 2 |
| 1 | green | 2023-01-31 | 5 |
| 1 | green | 2023-02-28 | 5 |
| 1 | green | 2023-03-31 | 5 |
| 1 | green | 2023-04-30 | 5 |
| 1 | green | 2023-05-31 | 5 |
| 1 | green | 2023-06-30 | 5 |
| 2 | green | 2023-01-31 | 1 |
| 2 | green | 2023-02-28 | 2 |
| 2 | green | 2023-03-31 | 3 |
| 2 | green | 2023-04-30 | 4 |
| 2 | green | 2023-05-31 | 4 |
| 2 | green | 2023-06-30 | 4 |

Comment: Do you have a separate table containing a list of possible colours?

Comment: Yes. I have separate table containing the colours and separate table containing id + colour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by calculating the SUM in a separate CTE and eventually UNION with the missing ones:

```
with sales(id, colour, payment_date, amount) as (
    select 1, 'red', cast( '2023-01-04' as date), 2  union all
    select 1, 'green', cast( '2023-01-04'as date), 5  union all
    select 2, 'green', cast( '2023-01-04'as date), 1  union all
    select 2, 'green', cast('2023-02-04'as date), 1  union all
    select 2, 'green', cast( '2023-03-04'as date), 1  union all
    select 2, 'green', cast( '2023-04-04' as date), 1 
),
report_dates(dat) as (
    select cast( '2022-12-31' as date) union all
    select cast( '2023-01-31' as date) union all
    select cast( '2023-02-28' as date) union all
    select cast( '2023-03-31' as date) union all
    select cast( '2023-04-30' as date) union all
    select cast( '2023-05-31' as date) union all
    select cast( '2023-06-30'as date) 
),
stats as (
    select s.id, s.colour, r.dat, 
        sum(s.amount) over(partition by s.colour, s.id order by r.dat) as cum_amount
    from (select dat, lag(dat) over(order by dat) as from_dat from report_dates) r
    join sales s on s.payment_date between coalesce(r.from_dat, cast('0001-01-01'as date)) and r.dat
)
select * from (
    select s.id, s.colour, r.dat, s.cum_amount
    from report_dates r
    join stats s on s.dat <= r.dat
    
    union all
    
    select s.id, s.colour, r.dat, 0
    from report_dates r
    , (select distinct id, colour from sales) s
    where not exists(select 1 from stats st where st.dat <= r.dat and st.id = s.id and st.colour = s.colour) 
) t
order by id, colour desc, dat
;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/ILZn5lFc

Answer (score 0):

This solution works, but very slow on real data (> 10mln rows of sales)

```
SELECT
    sales.id
    ,sales.colour
    ,report_dates.date
    ,SUM(sales.amount)
FROM report_dates
LEFT JOIN sales ON EOMONTH(sales.payment_date) <= report_dates.date
GROUP BY sales.id, sales.colour, report_dates.date
ORDER BY sales.id,  sales.colour, report_dates.date
```

Comment: This doesn't give the empty sales EOMONTH for each id and product. Like the question requested

Comment: I agree. I edit the question, it doesn't needed empty months before payment date anymore.